# pyCharm debugging: JRE without jstack?

Tags: java, pycharm, jstack

I need to debug pyCharm community version on Windows 7 and try to follow what their [manual](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348667) says:

> **JStack**
>
> This command line utility is provided with the JDK installation and
>   can be found in JAVA_HOME\bin directory. Make sure to use the same or
>   close JDK version to the one the IDE runs under (see Help | About). It
>   will not work if IDE runs under 32-bit JDK and you run jstack from the
>   64-bit JDK distribution and vice versa.
>
> To use jstack you need the IDE process identifier (PID). PID can be
>   obtained using jps utility that is located in the same directory as
>   jstack.
>
> jps -mv

My pyCharm: help/about reads: JRE 1.7.0_40 b43 x86

How ever, in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin` there is no `jps` and no `jstack`. I'm not used to the command line in Windows - perhaps I'm doing something wrong here? Am I supposed to look in a different directory? I could not find any system wide environmental variable `JAVA_HOME` what could give any clues here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need a *Java Development Kit* (JDK) instead of a *Java Runtime Environment* (JRE).

It is a bit larger but has many other dev tools (like `jstack`, `jps`, `jvisualvm`, etc., even the source code of Java). Download and install one to see the differences.